# Is there any option to automate APIs using Java and Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have lots of REST APIs to automate. I know that it  can be automated using SOAPUI and Groovy/Javascript.

But I am looking for solution to automate APIs using Selenium webdriver and JAVA. I have already searched for similar solution but unable to find.

Comment: Maybe you could use something else, like JSoup.

Comment: @Helping Hands: I don't understand the question, can you give an example and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @slowy - We want to write some automated test cases with assertion. But Don't want to use soap ui amd groovy. We prefer Java only.

Comment: @HelpingHands: That... still doesn't give me a context to give you a decent answer, I think. So, you have a rest service and you want to call it with given params and assert the response - basically an integration test for your rest service, right? Have you considered something like using apache http client and org.json library?

Comment: @slowy - Yes what's what I am looking for. Does that possible using Java?

Comment: @HelpingHands, yeah, those are libraries for java... depending on the framework you are using to _provide_ you're service, you can also generate client proxies, check for instance resteasy: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium webdriver only for browser automation. Webdriver is only for driving the browser like launch, close, maximize, minimize, screenshot the browser etc...during this automation if you need to test API you can send resquest to the required API from any one of the programming language like java, c#, javascript,etc... and you have to receive the response from the API. You have to test you get the expected response for the given resquest. Selenium webdriver is nothing to do with API testing.